# How to display products in category page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I m new to magento, I have created home page using sample data and created categories,sub-categories. For example,

```
                                Household items 
                                    |
                                  kitchenware 
                                    |
                                  microwave  oven.
```

Sub-category kitchenware I have created new 2 products. so in category products checked that 2 products and saved.

But refresh my home page, it will not display that products.

What my mistake?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my page for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Admin panel check for the below points for that particular category

- Under `General Information` set `Is Active` to `Yes`
- Set the field `Include To Navigation` as `Yes`
- Under `Custom Design` set the field `Use Parent Category Settings` to `Yes`

Then refresh your cache and try ReIndex then reload your home page

Comment: already done from your first 3 steps. May i know what is  list item and how to delete cache,reindex?

Comment: under System Tab - Cache Management/select all/ Actions - DISABLE/ then Flush Magento Cache & Flush Storage Cache.

under System Tab - Index Management/Select All / Reindex Data

Comment: @PANDAV: Still i can't get?

Answer (score 0):

This seems the re-indexing issue, from your admin, Mouse-over the `System` menu and from drop-down click `Index Management`, a new page with a grid will load, select all check-boxes and click the `submit` button on top right of the grid. keep the drop-down of `actions` as `Reindex Data`.

Comment: so is it working now?

Comment: did you refreshed the cache? can you post the link of your site?

Comment: :) this is your local installation link, we can't access it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56627/discussion-between-mtm-and-selva).

Comment: you are trying to display the products on homepage, can you post the code that is used to accomplish.